# When the countdowntimer finished i will go next activity?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have two activity set countdown timer in MainActivity, I want when countdown timer finished it will go next activity.but it's not going to next activity its show timer.
here is my code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView txtViewDays,txtViewHours,txtViewMinutes,txtViewSecond;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtViewDays = findViewById(R.id.days);
    txtViewHours = findViewById(R.id.hours);
    txtViewMinutes = findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    txtViewSecond = findViewById(R.id.seconds);

    start_countdown_timer();
}

private void start_countdown_timer()
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setLenient(false);

    final long[] startTime = new long[1];

    String endTime = "23.06.2019, 22:56:10";
    long milliseconds=0;

    final CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    Date endDate;
    try {
        endDate = formatter.parse(endTime);
        milliseconds = endDate.getTime();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    startTime[0] = System.currentTimeMillis();


    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            Long serverUptimeSeconds =
                    (millisUntilFinished - startTime[0]) / 1000;

            String daysLeft = String.format("%d", serverUptimeSeconds / 86400);
            txtViewDays.setText(daysLeft);

            String hoursLeft = String.format("%d", (serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600);
            txtViewHours.setText(hoursLeft);

            String minutesLeft = String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
            txtViewMinutes.setText(minutesLeft);
            Log.d("minutesLeft",minutesLeft);

            String secondsLeft = String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
            txtViewSecond.setText(secondsLeft);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,New.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    };
    mCountDownTimer.start();
}
}
```

What can I do?
N.B : code is collected and I also try but I can't.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With your code you need 1561330519961ms that means several days must pass in order for onFinish method to be called. I tried your code with 1min for the timer instead

```
milliseconds = endDate.getTime();
```

and worked just fine. After the timer finished it changed activity.

---edit---

This sample code will run for 6 seconds and then call the onFinish method

```
milliseconds = 6000
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Myclass.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
};
mCountDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: I don't understand,can u more explain this.thank u for your response @Chris Papantonis

Comment: By using getTime() the number that is returned is 1561330519961ms that correlates to 433702 days. And because you dont wait 433702 days it never finishes. You should check if the endDate.getTime(); is the number you except. Because getTime method returns how many ms have passed since January 1, 1970

Comment: Sorry, maybe you didn't understand my question.in my code I've already set my time in String endTime = "23.06.2019, 22:56:10; I want to know when endTime finish then it's going to next activity.thank u for your response@Chris Papantonis

Comment: Yes when the timer runs out then it will go to the next activity.

Comment: i was trying but it's not work.can u check please and show me this code.thank u@Chris Papantonis